# Rails passing in variables into view helper methods from form selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a bit of code in my `user.rb` model like this:

```
def self.aggregate(articles)
    array = []
    articles.each do |a|
        array << {
            :id => a.nid, 
            :views => a.daily_view_metrics.sum_views(a.nid),
            :date => a.daily_view_metrics.latest_date(a.nid),
            :title => a.daily_view_metrics.latest_title(a.nid),
            :visits => a.daily_view_metrics.sum_visits(a.nid)
            }
    end
    return array
end
```

In my `user_controller` I pass into the `show` method `@metrics = User.aggregate(@articles)` (@articles being simply a subset of articles for that user)

Now in my view (`user#show`) i call `@metrics.each do |m|` and then output all the different things in a table. Now according to this [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) it seems that the link_to method with a url parameter seems to be the best way to have users dynamically switch what they want to sort against.

How can I input that url parameter to sort the array? I tried calling `@metrics.sort_by{|h| h[params[:sort]]}.each do |m|` with `:sort` being the url parameter from my links (i.e. the views table header link click passes `:sort => ":views"` in. Essentially I am trying to do this `sort_by{|h| h[:views]}` since that works fine for sorting the array. However nothing happens. The array isn't sorted.

EDIT:

I solved it by making the aggregate method pass the key in as a string (i.e. "id" as opposed to :id). then the url params works beautifully.

`<%= link_to "Views", :sort => "views"%>` now sorts it by views in ascending order.

Comment: Exactly, pass it as string "views" and then you can always to do `.to_sym` if you need to. `params[:sort] # => "views"` `params[:sort].to_sym # => :views`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order in `descending` mode you can negate `-` the element that you are using to sort by.
Ordering by `ascending` and then do `revert` to your collection is inefficient.

For instance

```
$> [{a: 'a1', b: 1}, {a: 'a2', b: 2}].sort_by{ |h| -h[:b] }
# => [{:a=>"a2", :b=>2}, {:a=>"a1", :b=>1}] 

$> [{a: 'a1', b: 1}, {a: 'a2', b: 2}].sort_by{ |h| h[:b] }
# => [{:a=>"a1", :b=>1}, {:a=>"a2", :b=>2}]
```

In the form of your view, you will have something like this (a RadioButton e.g but it could be a Select or whatever you prefer):

```
 <%= radio_button_tag 'radio_order', 'ascending', true %> Ascending
 <%= radio_button_tag 'radio_order', 'descending' %> Descending
 <%= submit_tag "Order" %>
```

Then in your helper get the value using `params[:radio_order]`:

```
aggregate('views', params[:radio_order])
```

Comment: I know how to sort (as you can see above in my code) but I how do I get this from a form field into the view helper?

Comment: I edited my question. The more dynamic way seems to be with url params but I cannot get them working with the `sort_by{}` statement. Please advise